# How to make a Relativelayout clickable?

Tags: android, android-layout, styles

I have a layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/imageView_bg"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dip"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="25dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

button_bg.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" 
            android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"/>

    </selector>
```

imageView_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_pressed" 
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_normal"/>

</selector>
```

The image view and button have pressed images.when the user clicks on the view ,wants to press both imageview and button(Showing pressed images).But it does not show pressed images. How to achieve this? Where is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you attach an OnClickListener to your RelativeLayout?

Comment: are they stacked on top of each other ?

Comment: replace the image view by a layout, in which you put the button, and add duplicate parent state to the button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it solves the problem

```
((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
     for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup .getChildCount(); i++) {

       View viewChild = viewGroup .getChildAt(i);
       viewChild.setPressed(true);

          }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 18):

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {}
 });
```

Comment: If you are receiving ""RelativeLayout cannot be resolved to a type", make sure you are importing the following at the top of your java file: import android.widget.RelativeLayout; and import android.view.View;

Comment: Can't you just set  `android:clickable="true"` ?

Comment: also dont forget to add android:clickable="false" to views inside relativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.Place RelativeLayout inside the FrameLayout.